# Displaying JSON data in a loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to display the JSON data in my PHP. The data is coming as a loop. The raw data looks like this :

```
[{
    "count": 3,
    "not": "New Intender details entered"
},{
    "count": 3,
    "not": "New Intender details entered"
},{
    "count": 3,
    "not": "New Intender details entered"
}]
```

My AJAX script is as follows:

```
function addmsg(type, msg) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    $.each(obj, function(index, value) {
        var count = value.count;
        var not = value.not;
        alert(not);
        $('#msg_count').html(count);
        $('#notification').html(not);
    });
}

function waitForMsg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "notification/select.php",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 50000,
        success: function(data){
            addmsg("new", data);
            setTimeout(waitForMsg, 1000);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(waitForMsg, 15000);
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForMsg();
});
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<span id="msg_count"></span>
<span id="notification"></span>
```

The issue I am facing is that `msg_count` is showing fine. Now notification is a loop, which means it contains more than one record. When I am calling it through `span`, it's just showing one record. The rest of the records are not showing. I have given an `alert(not)` which is alerting all the records. I have only problem in showing in html as `<span id="notification"></span>`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? When you are in the `$.each` loop and when you first iterate over it does `$('#notification')` have the "not" value? Also after the loop iterates three times the `html` function seems to override the previous value of the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If notification is showing loop data then you have to add all not in not variable then show it in notification span. The code can as follows:

```
 function addmsg(type, msg) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        var not = "";
        $.each(obj, function(index, value) {
            var count = value.count;
            not += value.not+"<br/>";
            $('#msg_count').html(count);

        });
    $('#notification').html(not);
    }
```

Comment: working perfect. :) How will i give a break after each record..Now its showing all together..